# How to run sudo command using putty

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I'm just getting started with Linux environment. SO the terms sudo, bash and putty are all very new to me.

I'm based on windows local machine.I'm using putty to upload,delete,and create file into a remote Linux server.I have to use putty to bridge the gap.I can actually login successfully using putty.

The problem now, I just have no idea on how to run the sudo command to do anything to the server. Where do I start as I don't even see any window to type out anything in putty screen.

When I run Putty.exe I only see session,terminal,window,connection.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are successfully connected, the putty window will contain a shell prompt like `you:~$ ` (or maybe just `$`, or a password prompt if you don't have a public key on the server) and you can type your commands there.  Your problem description is very vague, but indicates that you are probably not successfully connected to the server in the first place.  Maybe a firewall is blocking port 22?  Anyway, not a programming question; nominated for migration to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that sudo is not entirely a command by itself. It requires an argument of a command, such as executing a script. What sudo does is grant you super-user privileges for the execution of the command. (You can think of it as "super-user do: command").

While I'm not familiar with using Putty, if you have managed to successfully login to the server you are targeting, you should be able to navigate to the "terminal" window and execute commands from there.

I recommend following this guide:
http://internal.math.arizona.edu/services/computing/remote-access/shell/putty

Once you're connected to the remote computer, you can begin executing commands, although if you don't know what they do, you should really be careful in your choice of executing them.

Comment: Especially `sudo` should be kept to a minimum, especially until you know roughly what the commands do, and when to use the privileges that `sudo` adds.